# Migration Spring Cloud Stream v2 to Spring Cloud Stream v4 for org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream

### Introduction

I'm currently using `Sink` interface from Spring-cloud-stream v2: https://javadoc.io/doc/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-stream/2.0.0.RELEASE/index.html

I have writed unit test to test my code.

#### The code of my project that uses these annotations before migration:

**StreamUtils.java**

```java
package com.enterprise.production.event.consumer;

import com.enterprise.production.model.message.EnergyMeasure;
import com.enterprise.production.model.message.EnergyProductionMessage;
import com.enterprise.production.model.message.Units;
import com.enterprise.production.model.time.InstantPeriod;
import com.enterprise.production.repository.entity.ProductionEntity;
import com.enterprise.production.stream.service.ProductionMessageConverter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.Sink;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import static com.enterprise.production.event.consumer.ProductionMessageConsumerIT.NOW;

@Component
@Slf4j
public class StreamUtils {

    @Autowired
    private Sink sink;

    @Autowired
    ProductionMessageConverter productionMessageConverter;

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;


    public List<ProductionEntity> generateAndSend2MessagesWith2Productions(int start, int end, String deviceId, String username, String tenantId, String unitsValue, String startDate) {
        List<ProductionEntity> result = new ArrayList<>();
        IntStream.rangeClosed(start, end)
                .boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                .stream()
                .forEach(i -> {
                    int dateInc = i * 4;
                    Instant period1From = Instant.parse(startDate).plus(dateInc, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
                    Instant period1To = Instant.parse(startDate).plus(dateInc + 1, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
                    Instant period2From = Instant.parse(startDate).plus(dateInc + 2, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
                    Instant period2To = Instant.parse(startDate).plus(dateInc + 3, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
                    Instant expiry = Instant.parse("2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z");
//                    dateInc = dateInc + 4;

                    EnergyMeasure production1 = EnergyMeasure.builder()
                                                             .period(new InstantPeriod(period1From, period1To))
                                                             .expiry(expiry)
                                                             .production(1.6)
                                                             .networkConsumption(8.0)
                                                             .selfConsumption(1.6)
                                                             .build();
                    EnergyMeasure production2 = EnergyMeasure.builder()
                                                             .period(new InstantPeriod(period2From, period2To))
                                                             .expiry(expiry)
                                                             .production(1.6)
                                                             .networkConsumption(0.0)
                                                             .selfConsumption(1.6)
                                                             .build();

                    Map<String, Units> units = ImmutableMap.<String, Units>builder()
                            .put("production", new Units(unitsValue))
                            .put("selfConsumption", new Units(unitsValue))
                            .put("networkConsumption", new Units(unitsValue))
                            .build();

                    EnergyProductionMessage message = EnergyProductionMessage.builder()
                                                     .deviceId(deviceId)
                                                     .username(username)
                                                     .tenantId(tenantId)
                                                     .units(units)
                                                     .solarEnergies(Arrays.asList(production1, production2))
                                                     .build();

                    List<ProductionEntity> productions = productionMessageConverter.convert(message);
                    productions.forEach(productionEntity -> productionEntity.setExpiry(computeTtl(productionEntity.getBeginTs())));
                    result.addAll(productions);
                    sendMessage(message);
                });
        return result;
    }

    private long computeTtl(Instant fromBeginTs) {
        return fromBeginTs.atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).plusMonths(25).toEpochSecond()
                - NOW.toEpochMilli() / 1000;
    }

    public void sendMessage(EnergyProductionMessage message)  {
        sink.input().send(getMessage(message));
    }

    public Message<EnergyProductionMessage> getMessage(EnergyProductionMessage message){
        return  MessageBuilder.withPayload(message).build();
    }

    public void sendMessage(String payload) throws IOException {
        EnergyProductionMessage energyProductionMessage = objectMapper.readValue(payload,
                                                                                 EnergyProductionMessage.class);
        Message<EnergyProductionMessage> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(energyProductionMessage).build();
        sink.input().send(message);
    }
}
```

**ProductionMessageConsumerIT.java**

```java
package com.enterprise.production.event.consumer;

import com.enterprise.production.Application;
import com.enterprise.production.client.ClientException;
import com.enterprise.production.model.message.EnergyMeasure;
import com.enterprise.production.model.message.EnergyProductionMessage;
import com.enterprise.production.model.message.Units;
import com.enterprise.production.model.time.InstantPeriod;
import com.enterprise.production.repository.ProductionRepository;
import com.enterprise.production.repository.entity.ProductionEntity;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.EqualsBuilder;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.wiremock.AutoConfigureWireMock;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.ResourceLoader;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.time.Clock;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.*;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {Application.class, ProductionMessageConsumerIT.TestConfig.class})
@AutoConfigureWireMock(port = 0)
@ActiveProfiles("it")
public class ProductionMessageConsumerIT {

    public static final Instant NOW = Instant.parse("2018-07-15T15:15:21Z");

    @Autowired
    ProductionRepository productionRepository;

    @Autowired
    StreamUtils streamUtils;

    @Autowired
    ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

    @Configuration
    static class TestConfig {
        @Bean
        @Primary
        public Clock clockIT() {
            return Clock.fixed(NOW, ZoneOffset.UTC); // timestamp 1531667721
        }
    }

    public static final String CAS_TABLE_ENERGIES = "energies_v2";
    public static final String CAS_TABLE_ENERGIES30m = "energies30m_v2";

    // Some tests ...
}
```

#### The code of my project that use these annotations after migration:

StreamUtils.java

```java
package com.enterprise.production.event.consumer;

import com.enterprise.production.model.message.EnergyMeasure;
import com.enterprise.production.model.message.EnergyProductionMessage;
import com.enterprise.production.model.message.Units;
import com.enterprise.production.model.time.InstantPeriod;
import com.enterprise.production.repository.entity.ProductionEntity;
import com.enterprise.production.stream.service.ProductionMessageConverter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.DirectWithAttributesChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import static com.enterprise.production.event.consumer.ProductionMessageConsumerIT.NOW;

@Component
@Slf4j
public class StreamUtils {

    @Autowired
    ProductionMessageConverter productionMessageConverter;
    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    private DirectWithAttributesChannel sink;

    public List<ProductionEntity> generateAndSend2MessagesWith2Productions(int start, int end, String deviceId, String username, String tenantId, String unitsValue, String startDate) {
        List<ProductionEntity> result = new ArrayList<>();
        IntStream.rangeClosed(start, end)
                .boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                .stream()
                .forEach(i -> {
                    int dateInc = i * 4;
                    Instant period1From = Instant.parse(startDate).plus(dateInc, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
                    Instant period1To = Instant.parse(startDate).plus(dateInc + 1, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
                    Instant period2From = Instant.parse(startDate).plus(dateInc + 2, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
                    Instant period2To = Instant.parse(startDate).plus(dateInc + 3, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
                    Instant expiry = Instant.parse("2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z");
//                    dateInc = dateInc + 4;

                    EnergyMeasure production1 = EnergyMeasure.builder()
                            .period(new InstantPeriod(period1From, period1To))
                            .expiry(expiry)
                            .production(1.6)
                            .networkConsumption(8.0)
                            .selfConsumption(1.6)
                            .build();
                    EnergyMeasure production2 = EnergyMeasure.builder()
                            .period(new InstantPeriod(period2From, period2To))
                            .expiry(expiry)
                            .production(1.6)
                            .networkConsumption(0.0)
                            .selfConsumption(1.6)
                            .build();

                    Map<String, Units> units = ImmutableMap.<String, Units>builder()
                            .put("production", new Units(unitsValue))
                            .put("selfConsumption", new Units(unitsValue))
                            .put("networkConsumption", new Units(unitsValue))
                            .build();

                    EnergyProductionMessage message = EnergyProductionMessage.builder()
                            .deviceId(deviceId)
                            .username(username)
                            .tenantId(tenantId)
                            .units(units)
                            .solarEnergies(Arrays.asList(production1, production2))
                            .build();

                    List<ProductionEntity> productions = productionMessageConverter.convert(message);
                    productions.forEach(productionEntity -> productionEntity.setExpiry(computeTtl(productionEntity.getBeginTs())));
                    result.addAll(productions);
                    sendMessage(message);
                });
        return result;
    }

    private long computeTtl(Instant fromBeginTs) {
        return fromBeginTs.atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).plusMonths(25).toEpochSecond()
                - NOW.toEpochMilli() / 1000;
    }

    public void sendMessage(EnergyProductionMessage message) {
        sink.send(getMessage(message));
    }

    public Message<EnergyProductionMessage> getMessage(EnergyProductionMessage message) {
        return MessageBuilder.withPayload(message).build();
    }

    public void sendMessage(String payload) throws IOException {
        EnergyProductionMessage energyProductionMessage = objectMapper.readValue(payload,
                EnergyProductionMessage.class);
        Message<EnergyProductionMessage> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(energyProductionMessage).build();
        sink.send(message);
    }
}
```

**ProductionMessageConsumerIT.java**

```java
package com.enterprise.production.event.consumer;

import com.enterprise.production.Application;
import com.enterprise.production.client.ClientException;
import com.enterprise.production.model.message.EnergyMeasure;
import com.enterprise.production.model.message.EnergyProductionMessage;
import com.enterprise.production.model.message.Units;
import com.enterprise.production.model.time.InstantPeriod;
import com.enterprise.production.repository.ProductionRepository;
import com.enterprise.production.repository.entity.ProductionEntity;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.EqualsBuilder;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.AutoConfigureTestDatabase;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.AutoConfigureDataJpa;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.AutoConfigureTestEntityManager;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.wiremock.AutoConfigureWireMock;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.ResourceLoader;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.time.Clock;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.*;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows;

@SpringBootTest(classes = {Application.class, ProductionMessageConsumerIT.TestConfig.class})
@AutoConfigureWireMock(port = 0)
@ActiveProfiles("it")
public class ProductionMessageConsumerIT {

    public static final Instant NOW = Instant.parse("2018-07-15T15:15:21Z");
    public static final String CAS_TABLE_ENERGIES = "energies_v2";
    public static final String CAS_TABLE_ENERGIES30m = "energies30m_v2";
    @Autowired
    ProductionRepository productionRepository;
    @Autowired
    StreamUtils streamUtils;
    @Autowired
    ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

// Some Tests ...

    @Configuration
    static class TestConfig {
        @Bean
        @Primary
        public Clock clockIT() {
            return Clock.fixed(NOW, ZoneOffset.UTC); // timestamp 1531667721
        }
    }
}
```

### Problem

The interface `Sink` is not on the new version 4.0.0 of Spring-cloud-stream https://javadoc.io/doc/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-stream/4.0.0/org/springframework/cloud/stream/messaging/package-summary.html so I needed to replace the past `Sink` in my code to new class `DirectWithAttributesChannel` of Spring-cloud-stream, but when I do that I got this error:

```
Field sink in com.enterprise.production.event.consumer.StreamUtils required a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.DirectWithAttributesChannel' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.DirectWithAttributesChannel' in your configuration.
```

#### Question

Does someone know how to migrate `Sink` interfqce from spring-cloud-stream v2 to spring-cloud-stream v4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The annotation-based programming model comprised of `EnableBinding,` `Sink,` `Source`, and `Processor` components has long been deprecated and completely removed in the `4.x` versions of Spring Cloud Stream. You should move to the functional model based on the Spring Cloud Function architecture. In the functional model, a `Sink` can be translated as a `java.util.function.Consumer`, a `Source` as a `java.util.function.Supplier` and a `Processor` via `java.util.function.Function`. In addition to these, there is also a `StreamBridge` API for sending data on-demand. All these can be found in the reference docs. Since you are using `4.0.x` here are the ref docs for the latest `4.0.x`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/4.0.3/reference/html/

In the old model, when you use a `Sink`, you usually use that with the `EnableBinding(Sink.class)` and then use something like `StreamListener` to receive the messages sent through the sink. The sink is responsible for consuming the records from the messaging middleware and send to the input channel which is then listened by the `StreamListener`. All these annotation based programming model and components are removed from the framework in preference to the functional model. By looking at the code examples you provided, it looks like you are trying to generate some data and then send that to an input channel. If your use-case ends there, then I would suggest using Spring Integration directly as it has first class support for working at the messaging channels level. Spring Cloud Stream is a higher-level abstraction that uses Spring Integration internally.

If you want to send data to a middleware destination after generating it within your application, then you can use `StreamBridge`.

```
@Autowired 
StreamBridge streamBridge;
...
streamBridge.send("binding-name", data);
}
```

or if you want to simply listens on a middleware destination (Kafka topic for example, then you can use a standard `java.util.function.Consumer` (or `Function` if you want to send the data out to another destination).

```
@Bean
public Consumer<Data> consume() {
 data -> {
   // custom code, maybe StreamBridge.send...
 }
}

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.consume-in-0.destination: <Middleware destination>
```

or

```
@Bean
public Function<DataIn, DataOut> function() {
 return in -> {
  ...
  return dataOut;
 }
}

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.function-in-0.destination: <Middleware destination>

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.function-out-0.destination: <Middleware destination>
```